# How to resolve "Not Found" + "403 Forbidden" errors on "Request New Password" link

Tags: users

When I click on the "Request New Password" button, I get the following message:

Not Found

The requested URL /user/password was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at berniesdogtraining.com Port 80

Comment: Your web server either doesn't have mod_rewrite enabled or there is some mis-configuration that is preventing the rewrite rules from working. You can browse the site with q=<path> parameter (e.g. http://berniesdogtraining.com/?q=user) until you've figured it out.

Comment: Shawn Conn is right. You can also check https://www.drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls specifically the Drupal 7.x section to check the configuration. It should also display an error if it has.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to use ?q=user to get into the site, but no matter what I click on I get this message:                                         Not Found

The requested URL /admin/settings/clean-urls was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache Server at berniesdogtraining.com Port 80